# Can we get PRT(Primary Refresh Token) with Azure AD registered not Joined?

Tags: azure-active-directory

As I understand, IE or Edge can obtain the PRT to use it for sso with any Saas application that trusts Azure AD. Is that correct?

I want to use this mechanism for the PCs that are joined the ADDS that is not synchronized to Azure AD. I mean I have 2 different forests on premises and one is synchronized to Azure AD and the other is not synchronized and the PCs reside on the not synchronized one.

In this situation, the PCs is not joined but registered in Azure AD.

Can we get PRT even when this situation?

O.M

Comment: I ran dsregcmd.exe to check  if I obtain the PRT under the status with Azure AD registered but AzureAdPrt  is always NO. I would like to know this is by design or by something need to be done. 
I appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why AzureAdPrt is always NO seems to be a limitation of dsregcmd.exe command. It never show the status correctly whether the user obtains a PRT or not while the user's PC is "Azure AD registered".

I confirmed that by the following.

I found that the status "connected to windows" was appeared on "Pick an account" dialog if the user obtained a PRT.

"Pick an account" dialog is appeared when the user try to sign in at the first time after the user signed out intentionally.

Thanks
O.M